# Stop automatic scaling of axes

Tags: matlab, plot

I have this code:

```
function masterPiece()

figure
axis manual
axis([-10 10 -10 10])

plot(3,3,'Marker','o','MarkerFaceColor','red');
```

This produces the follwing image. How can I set the axis from -10 to 10?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the line `axis([-10 10 -10 10])` *after* the `plot` line.

Or: include `hold on` *before* the `plot`. That will freeze the axis properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
figure
axis manual
axis([-10 10 -10 10])
hold on
plot(3,3,'Marker','o','MarkerFaceColor','red');
```

otherwise a new plot is created